# How to fix Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores error

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ubuntu-22.04

I have a .NET CORE WEB API deployed in a VM running linux ubuntu 22.0 and I am encountering the error Below when running the application.

Here's the full exception message:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.StorePal.FromSystemStore(String storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, OpenFlags openFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags flags).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.<LocateCertificateWithPrivateKey>g__OpenStore|18_0(StoreLocation storeLocation)

This exception is thrown once I start to explicitly tell .NET where to find the certificate explicitly and use them. I just don't know why it still goes through the store to search for a certificate while I provided one explicitly
```

Here's the config code

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    var certificateFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mylivedomain/fullchain.pem";
    var privateKeyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mylivedomain/privkey.pem";

    options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(certificateFile, privateKeyFile, httpsOptions =>
        {
            httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
            // Additional HTTPS options can be configured here
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried this

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    var certificateFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mylivedomain/fullchain.pem";
    var privateKeyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mylivedomain/privkey.pem";
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, privateKeyFile);

    options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate, httpsOptions =>
        {
            httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
            // Additional HTTPS options can be configured here
        });
    });
});
```

I get the same exception. Even when the IP is set to 5001 it still does the same thing.

When the config code is completely removed the app uses the development certificate

Does anyone has a working solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that .NET regardless of the platform it is running on or the target Platform, it processes or tries to find certificates as how it would normally do in a Windows platform

This piece of code here did the trick for me

```
X509Certificate2 certificate;

if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix || Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.MacOSX)
{
    //Reading filePath from appsettings.json
    certificate = new X509Certificate2(builder.Configuration.GetSection($"Certificate:PKX").Value, builder.Configuration.GetSection($"Certificate:Password").Value);
}
else
{
    certificate = new X509Certificate2(builder.Configuration.GetSection($"Certificate:PKX").Value, builder.Configuration.GetSection($"Certificate:Password").Value);
}

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(YourOpenPortNumber, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions
        {
            ServerCertificate = certificate
        });
    });
});
```

Also make sure that

```
UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Is removed.

One more important thing worth mentioning is that, if your certificate goes along with its key, for this to work you'll have to convert the SSL/TLS certificate into PKX which will combine the two into one. From my experience here, if you try to do the following when loading your certificate

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToFilanameOrActualFileName, pathToPrivateKeyFilanameOrActualPrivateKeyFileName);
```

It will trigger the default behaviour where .NET tries to load the certificate from LocalMachine which won't work for unix and unix-like Platforms.

Having all that should resolve the issue.
**Hope this helps you as well.**

***Happy C# Coding.***